# Is there any google API by which we can calculate distance between multiple points?

Tags: php, google-distancematrix-api

I have to calculate distance between multiple points through google distance matrix API.
I have a plugin which has inputs like Pickup address, pickup via, dropoff-address and then a checkbox to select return drive.
If return drive box is checked, then we have return pickup, return via, return dropoff inputs.

I have used distance matrix API to calculate distance between: 
1) pickup address and pickup via
2) Then pickup via to dropoff address.
and then added the two.

Now if I have to calculate the return drive distance, would I need to do this same method of selecting 2 at a time or is there a prebuilt function for this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro
I am not sure if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't helps. I am not sure how do I calculate distance between multiple points.